# What does enabling 'saves' do in the options menu?

Tags: the-stanley-parable

I have a feeling it is a joke, like the "achievements" one, which gives you an achievement called "achievement". But I don't want to lose my progress by not enabling it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Enabling saves does allow you to save in the middle of a run.

Since the game rarely takes more than 5-10 mins (with [perhaps one exception](http://thestanleyparable.wikia.com/wiki/Art_Ending)),  this isn't necessary but it allows you to save and reload so you don't have to keep replaying the early bits of the game.